# column "xxx" does not exist LINE 3: values(xxx,bla,bla)

Tags: python

Hi I have query string like this

```
executeQuery = '''insert into CarModel
                        (modeli,msubuqi,gamomshvebi)
                         values(%s,%s,%s)''' % ("BMW","X5","Jeep")
cursor.execute(executeQuery)
```

but when I execute It it gives me Error :
    column "BMW" does not exist LINE 3: values(BMW,X5,Jeep)
I don't know why it takes that "BMW" is column please Help I'm working on it whole day

Answer (score 0):

After the formatting, `executeQuery` is equals to:

```
executeQuery = '''insert into CarModel
                    (modeli,msubuqi,gamomshvebi)
                     values(BMW, X5, Jeep)'''
```

It's normal that SQL returns you that BMW isn't a column because you haven't had quotes around yours values. Use execute with parameters instead:

```
cursor.execute('''insert into CarModel(modeli,msubuqi,gamomshvebi)
                     values(?,?,?)''', ("BMW","X5","Jeep"))
```

Note the comma instead of `%`.

See [cursor.execute()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) definition for more information. I'm assuming that you're using SQLite, but it's the same convention for DB API in Python. Every well-known DB system use this interface.

#### Edit after comment

If you want to construct your SQL query, you can use your method but surround `%s` with quotes:

```
executeQuery = '''insert into CarModel(modeli,msubuqi,gamomshvebi)
                     values("%s","%s","%s")''' % ("BMW","X5","Jeep")
```

Comment: yes but I Am setting executeQuery string another place and then I use cursor.execute() so I cant use parameters